# Crystal Reports Subreport - Selecting data based on column clicked

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a number of reports with current and ytd columns(summary totals by salesman).  I want to be able to select the sub-report based on the column clicked. I have one sql procedure that selects current and one that selects ytd.  I want to use the same report format (without having to copy and modify it) for current and ytd.  Is there anyway of identifying what column is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports is pretty much just a reporting tool; it's not very interactive.

I'm more familiar with older versions of Crystal Reports, but as far as I know there aren't any `onClick` methods for columns that can be trapped using pure Crystal Reports.

Depending on how many columns you have, you can create a subreport for each column, but that may be prohibitively slow if you have a large number of columns you want to create subreports for.

If you're using C# or VB.NET to generate the report, you may have more options, but since the question isn't tagged with any programming languages, I'm going to assume this is pure Crystal Reports.